# Don't have permissions to copy some files using live USB

Tags: permissions, live-usb, backup

I tried installing "Gramps" software and it bricked my laptop.

I can boot but my Ubuntu Software icon is missing, my Files icon is missing, my wifi is disconnected.  Pretty much, I can't do anything with the computer.  I uninstalled the software but that didn't fix anything.

I decided to do a clean install.

I put in my Ubuntu live USB and I went to pull out my home files to preserve them before a clean install.

However, about 20% of the files, it says I can't copy them because I lack permission.  I read about 20 articles here for folks with similar problems and nothing I've tried has worked.

Comment: Likely nothing to with Gramps. Possibly a hardware problem with the disk. If you have Smartmontools on the live USB, have a look at the SMART data for the drive.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following command:

```
sudo cp /source-path/file /destination-path/
```

Yes, you should. For example if you want to copy all files of our ~/Document directory to your usb device mounted on /media/my_user_name/USB-dev you should use following command:

```
cp ~/Document/* /media/my_user_name/USB-dev
```

Comment: It says:  cp: missing destination file operand after '...'
Try 'cp --help' for more information.    Am I supposed to substitute ... for something?